# Combinatorics Problem Taylor Formula

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion

Proof that:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}x^{k}=(1-4x)^{-1/2},\mathopen|x\mathclose|<1/4$$

Hint:Use the Taylor formula to expand the RHS into a power series.

This is just a small part of a bigger problem  I'm trying to understand from the book Basic Sctochastic Processes by Brzezniak.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Have you even tried it? You have written the solution in your hint. Expand RHS by doing expansion and it is automatically giving solution

Answer (score 0):

The proof comes down to showing that 
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n}(-1)^n 4^n=\binom{2n}{n}.
$$
Note that 
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n}(-1)^n 4^n
=\frac{1(3)(5)\dotsb(2n-1)}{n!}2^n
=\frac{(1)(3)(5)\dotsb(2n-1)}{n!}\frac{(2)(4)(6)\dots (2n)}{(2)(4)(6)\dots (2n)}2^n
$$
You should be able to take it from here.